# When resetting tablet, Google password won't authenticate

Tags: google-account

I was told to reset my RCA Viking Pro 10 but now it keeps asking for Google account verification which I have input a minimum of 10 times. It keeps saying it is incorrect. The Google password works fine on my phone but not this device. I've even reset my password. How do I get past this?

Comment: In its current state, can you change soft keyboards? Look for a keyboard icon in the corner of the screen.

Comment: your problem is for google authentication OR only gmail old sync??
- Did you try to open your google account from a browser on your device?
- Did you setup your google account from original device setting?